# How to send a perl hash over a network socket?

Tags: perl, networking, serialization

i am working on a tool that consists of a server and multiple clients. 
The clients create a hash that needs to be sent to the server via network socket.

I thought *nstore* would be the right thing to do it, but i could not find a way to retrieve the data on the server.

Could anyone tell my how to properly do this?

Regards Nick

PS: I know that I could write the data in some kind of string format and reconstruct it on the server, but i am wondering if that could be avoided.

Comment: Wouldn't you just call `Storable::retrieve` or `Storable::fd_retrieve`?

Comment: I would say "I know that i _should_ serialize data" instead of "could write data in some kind..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send:

```
Storable::nstore_fd( \%hash, $socket );
```

Retrieve:

```
my $ref = Storable::fd_retrieve( $socket );
```

I think that is all you need. If you don't know how to create the socket--or don't have a protocol to initiate this--*that* is a more pressing issue, I would think. See [`IO::Socket::INET`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aINET) for the former.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for, I was trying to use nstore without the fd...

Answer (score 5):

As alternatives to already posted solutions, you can use [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=YAML) or [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=JSON), too.

Answer (score -3):

you can combine Data::Dump and eval. The idea is to serialize your data structure (hash), transmit and decode (evaluate):

```
$a = { ... }
$serializable_a = Data::Dump::dump($a)

# transmit && receive

$a_clone = eval( $serializable_a_received ) ;
```

Comment: That will probably work out but if security is only a little bit important or may possibly become (true for the most projects) you definitely should NOT do that. This way anyone might inject arbitrary Perl code into your server and run it in your session ...

Comment: -1, `eval STRING` is never a valid option for data sent over a network.